# O que significa " | " em TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
export type Teste = Observable<'exemplo' | any>;
```

- O que significa a barra `|` dentro do argumento genérico?
- É algum comparador entre o tipo `any` e a `string` por exemplo?

Comment: significa ou como na maioria das linguagens

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto é usado em algo chamado *union types* (tipos unidos) também chamado de *sum types*, em oposição a *product types* ou *intersection types* (tipos intersecionados*) que usa a sintaxe de `&`.

Não deixa de ser um OU, mas não do jeito que se conhece, não é uma exatamente expressão lógica, embora possa ser vista como uma. Não é executado um OR em tempo de execução. Ele indica que o tipo genérico parametrizado ali pode ser um dos tipos listados ali, então no caso pode usar esse objeto parametrizado com o tipo `exemplo` (sem aspas) ou o tipo `any`, qualquer um dos dois seria aceito. Porém neste caso não faz sentido por `any` envolve todos os tipos então envolve o `exemplo` também, poderia escrever só:

```
export type Teste = Observable<any>;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/UnionSyntax.ts).

Comment: Posso usar o `&`?

Comment: Sim, é possível, isto chama-se *intersection types*.

Answer (score 9):

Um tipo de união descreve um valor que pode ser um dos vários tipos. Usamos a barra vertical (|) para separar cada tipo, então [ number | string | booleano ] é o tipo de valor que pode ser um número, uma string ou um booleano.

Answer (score -4):

É uma forma de união de tipos. Entende-se assim:

```
tipo1 | tipo2

tipo1 OU tipo2

number OU string
```

Colocado como tipo de um parâmetro de uma função, por exemplo, você poderá receber esse parâmetro como um OU outro tipo que não terá erro.

Você pode encontrar mais informações [aqui na W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_union_types.php). Eles deixam bem resumido.